# Does a single shell command constitute reviewable code?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[A question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117610/9357) asks to have a command-line invocation of FFmpeg reviewed.  Is that reviewable code?

There is currently no language tag, though [shell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) [unix](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unix) could be added.

Let's not discuss whether a shell command containing an AWK one-liner is on-topic; such a post could be considered a question about [awk](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) as a programming language.

Does the complexity of the tool matter?  FFmpeg, as a suite of command-line programs (ignoring the FFmpeg library), has [a lot of features](http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html).

What if it were two shell commands to be invoked in succession?

Comment: Related question: [Do configuration files constitute reviewable code?](/q/6060/9357)

Comment: If rejected, the question might be suitable for [su], [unix.se], or [video.se].

Comment: Am I confused? [shell](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell) was created in 2012.

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: **Yes.**

Longer Answer: As long as it *works* and all requirements for a request are met I see no reason why not; code length has never been an explicit requirement of any review request.

There's the implicit expectation that no matter how simple it may seem to some, it constitutes an area of enough uncertainty to warrant a review for the one asking. Despite technically being a one-liner the linked post, to a blind eye, seems complex enough that I don't fault the asker for wondering if it's optimal.

Speaking generally, 'simple' and 'short' questions are easier to answer, tend to attract community members who may not answer often, and sometimes even [inexplicably](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/119358/have-a-safe-trip-or-not-depending-on-four-conditions) generate traffic.