# Understanding closed question concerns

Tags: discussion

I'm still in the process of figuring out many aspects of stackexchange, and a recent question of mine got closed after I responded to comments provided. I'm hoping to understand more about the feedback provided in the closed dialog so I'm posting here.

Here's the original [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236897/attempting-a-strategy-design-pattern-in-js?noredirect=1#comment465029_236897). And I found almost the exact same type of question for the python programming language from 6 years ago that has been upvoted and accepted in the community: [upvoted post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23033/strategy-design-pattern-in-python?rq=1). The closure message at the top is labeled 'off topic' and then (here's the part I'm confused about) a tag about "authorship of code is provided  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygUpv.jpg).

I'd love to understand a bit about where this question went wrong in terms of being outside the bounds of code review's posting requirements, and how the "authorship of code" principle was violated in my case? Thanks!

Comment: not line for line in any way. Perhaps, that's what confused the moderators? The chapter was about making duck objects, but their code was in Java a language that allows for interfaces, so I was fumbling using javascript which doesn't require them. Thanks for assisting!

Comment: Old posts may have been posted under old policy, please don't use those as example. Especially *that* old.

Comment: @Mast gotcha! good to know

Comment: If you could alleviate some of the concerns, perhaps reopening would be more constructive than guessing at what the reviewers thought was intolerable about your question. I can make a couple of guesses as to why it *could* be considered off-topic, but it's a bit of a grey area and I don't like guesswork.

Answer (score 8):

The way Stack Exchange works is that volunteers get reputation, and when a user gets [3000 reputation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) they can vote to close questions. These moderators are different than [elected moderators](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), who have diamonds displayed next to their names.

Your question was deemed to violate the following rule by 3-5 users.

> **Authorship of code**: Since Code Review is a community where programmers improve their skills through peer review, we require that the code be [posted by an author or maintainer of the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654), that the code be [embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653), and that the poster know why the code is written the way it is.

This one rule actually has three independent but linked rules within it:

1. > we require that the code be [posted by an author or maintainer of the code](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654)

   In this case it is debatable who *the author* is. However you are a maintainer.

   In this situation the closers may have assumed you were neither; instead you just took the code from the book.
2. > that the code be [embedded directly](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3653)

   You have included the code. It is not this reason.
3. > the poster know why the code is written the way it is

   Some closers may have thought you were asking how the code works. A segment of your question can read as a if you're trying to circumvent the rules.

   > Does the code below program correctly to interfaces, encapsulate changeable behavior, and employ composition in a reasonable manner?

   If the code does work as intended, the interfaces, etc., are correct then we would answer the question with "yes". But it doesn't stop there; since we're just random people on the internet we should provide proof that we are correct. And so we would be explaining how or why the code is correctly applying interfaces, etc.

So from my perspective I can see potentially two reasons to close your question for this reason. But let's look at another close reason too, as some may have voted to close for this too.

> Missing Review Context: Code Review requires [concrete code from a project, with enough code and / or context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652) for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

1. Linking to:

   > If your code was deemed to be **example code**, [too hypothetical to be meaningfully reviewed](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357), then we need you to provide concrete details.

   Your code doesn't really do much. It creates two objects which in some convoluted way add "I'm flying" and "not flying" to the page. I can see people voting to close your question for this reason.
2. > generic best practices are outside the scope of this site.

   Your question could also be thought of as a generic best practice as all you've implemented is a design pattern.

---

So to summarize, you post has as far as I can see three potential problems:

- It's not clear whether you're an author or maintainer.
- It may look like you're trying to circumvent our rules.
- Your post looks like example code / generic best practice.

In my opinion, your post was:

1. At the least, closed for the wrong reason.

   I've read the first chapter, and whilst I can see similarities, the code is your own.

   I also think it's rude of us to assume that you're trying to circumvent the rules.
2. I don't think your question is off-topic for MRC either.

   I'm used to a higher code density, and your code gives off a hint that it's example code.

   But I do think the question is answerable, there's enough context to answer this.

Comment: Granted 2012-2013 is pretty far back, but [1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/20718/23788), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/14226/23788), [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92199/23788), [4](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/139984/23788) and I bet a thousand other [tag:design-patterns] posts use similar example-ish code too. I don't see anything inherently wrong with the OP's question, reopened.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Honestly a lot of the [tag:design-patterns] questions aren't that well-suited for the site because they focus on hypothetical scenario's that are too hypothetical. A [tag:programming-challenge] is the middle road between a real problem and a text-book example showcasing a new theory/feature/function/library/whatever and a [tag:design-patterns] post often enough takes a wrong turn in that regard.

Comment: "deemed to violate the following rule by 3-5 users" 5, their names are in the revision history.

Comment: @Mast The new close notification allocates all 5 votes to one reason, even if there were a 3/2 split. Where the old notification showed both close reasons.

Comment: @Mast yes, and some of these names ring a particular "check twice before backing that close vote" bell.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Absolutely, it's a good thing all community moderation can be reversed by the rest of the community.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon When answering I was trying to find any reason to close the question, and honestly it was difficult to answer because everything felt like I was grasping at straws. I feel I've achieved my goal of showing any way those users may have thought the question was off-topic. AFAIK example code isn't off-topic, and [is just confusing way of saying missing context](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9149).

Comment: @Peilonrayz example *code* is sort-of off-topic, but example *projects* is for sure not off-topic. I'd consider this an example project and perfectly on-topic.